# "Failed to get Authorization" with a Google account secured with Okta

Tags: google, online-accounts

I have a Google account which is protected by Okta. When I add the Google account in the "Online Accounts" page, I go to the Google login form, I enter my username, which takes me to an Okta login form. I go through the Okta login workflow (MFA, Password) and then use the MFA on my Google account. This takes me to the Google OAUTH approval form for the GNOME integration, and then takes me back to the Online Account page, where the top bar shows "Credentials have expired", and it asks me to "Sign in to enable this account".

Any thoughts? I can live without the account being available, but it's very useful to have the OS integration!